# How to run Outlook 2010 as Administrator?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I need to run the Outlook 2010 as Administrator but I cannot find a way to run it when right-clicking the Outlook icon. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your user is the Admin, you don't need to run it as Admin.

Anyway, If you still want to do it:

[image: Shift+Right Click on the icon]

Make sure Outlook is closed before. (Check in task manager.) Otherwise the old non-admin Outlook will be the process used.